# How to put reversal rows as a new column in same report?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY_LOCATION;

Result -->
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
| Invt  | Doc_no | Location  | Qty   |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 00X7X |   5123 | Warehous1 |-123CS |
| 00X7X |   5123 | Warehous2 | 123CS |
| 00N6U |   5345 | Warehous5 |-456CS |
| 00N6U |   5345 | Warehous6 | 456CS |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+


Desired Result -->
+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------+
| Invt  | Doc_no | From Location | To Location | Qty   |
+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------+
| 00X7X |   5123 | Warehous1     | Warehous2   | 123CS |
| 00N6U |   5345 | Warehous5     | Warehous6   | 456CS |
+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------+
```

As you can see, I have a table that shows the location of the inventory. It goes out of one Warehouse and hence shows negative numbers in Quantity for that location. Then it goes to a new location and shows positive numbers in Quantity for that location.

I was hoping to get into one line, both the location the item is coming from, and to location to which it is going.

Please, can someone help me with getting the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What cols do you actually have? If the first, you will need to amend the table.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have edited the question to better explain it. Please do take a look again.

Comment: What is the CS? `456CS`

Comment: You need to amend the table to reflect the columns you actually need.

Comment: CS is short for Cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I used two derived tables. One with qty that start with `-` and another without. Join these two tables to get the from and to locations. Only reason I did it this way is it appears your qty field isn't numeric from the data your provided.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c9d74/6)**

```
select fromLoc.invt,
  fromLoc.doc_no,
  fromLoc.location as "From Location",
  toLoc.location as "To Locaiton",
  toLoc.qty
from
  (select * from INVENTORY_LOCATION where qty like '-%') fromLoc 
  join
    (select * from INVENTORY_LOCATION where qty not like '-%') toLoc
    on fromLoc.invt = toLoc.invt and fromLoc.doc_no = toLoc.doc_no
```

Comment: There is one more field 'total_lbs' which denotes the weight. Do I need to add another join for weight too? I tried adding the following:
    toLoc.total_lbs Weight

It works. But I'm not sure if it is accurate. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to pivot on INVT and DOC_NO?

```
SELECT
    INVT,
    DOC_NO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN QTY LIKE '-%' THEN LOCATION END) AS "FROM LOCATION",
    MAX(CASE WHEN QTY NOT LIKE '-%' THEN LOCATION END) AS "TO LOCATION",
    MAX(QTY) AS "Qty"
FROM
    INVENTORY_LOCATION
GROUP BY
    INVT,
    DOC_NO
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I get an error message when I run that code.

Comment: ERROR
    ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: That error would indicate you did not include the GROUP BY part of the command :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c9d7/1